# How to make Jackson read LocalDate written by GSON as a POJO

Tags: jackson, gson

Using Jackson (with the java.util.time Module installed (*)), how do we read the following into a `java.util.LocalDate`. It is NOT in any supported format and doesn't match any constructor or setters. How can we configure Jackson *fall back* to "GSON behaviour" (unsafe allocation + private field setters).

```json
{"dob": {day: 1, month: 2, year: 2023}}
```

```java
public class Test {
  java.util.LocalDate dob;
}
```

(*) Actually even without the module. Jackson has special handling to log errors if it detects a `LocalDate` even *without* the module.

Background: these values are written by a different process using `GSON` which is unaware of LocalDate and writes it as a vanilla object (using reflection to read the 3 internal fields).  It is not sensible to write a bespoke Jackson deserialiser for every potential type.